# pdflatex can't find aux file

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files

I'm trying to automate the creation of PDF documents from  tex files via command line.

I use the command 
**pdflatex C:\files\001.tex** 
and files named **001.aux**, 001.dvi, 001.log, 001.toc are created  in the same folder, but I get the message:

**! I can't find file `001.aux '**

But it really is in that folder. 
When ask " **Please type another input file name:** " I have the option of manually write  **C:\files\001.aux** , but I can`t do this all the time.

Even if i write
**pdflatex --output-directory="C:\files" --aux-directory="C:\files" C:\files\001.tex**
I get the same result

Comment: Perhaps you can show the details of how you are automating the process may be the bash/bat script.

Comment: Bat contains only one line per file:


**pdflatex --output-directory="C:\files\001" --aux-directory="C:\files\001" C:\files\001\001.tex**

Comment: pdflatex will look for files in the folder where your started pdflatex not where the main file resides. Switch to C:\files in your batch file with cd and then call pdflatex 001.tex.

Comment: I think that's not the problem. 
If i open a ms-dos console and write  **cd C:\Programas\MiKTeX29\miktex\bin** In that folder there is a file called **001.tex** Then i write **pdflatex 001.tex**

  but I get the same error.  **!I can't find file `001.aux '**

Comment: miktex will not find new files in a texmf-tree unless you update the fndb first. (But it is not a good idea to compile in a texmf tree: You could easily overwrite important files. Documents belongs in document folders.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the program was started from a read-only directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these as the contents of your bat file (say `compile.bat`)

```
@ECHO ON
cls
REM ECHO.

REM compile the tex document with pdflatex

CD /D %~dp0
pdflatex --output-directory="C:\files\001" --file-line-error --interaction=nonstopmode "001.tex" 
Pause
```

Save the `compile.bat` in the same folder as the main file (i.e., `001.tex`).

For a list of valid options to `pdflatex`, [refer to this link](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/pdflatex1.html)  or run `pdflatex --help` from command prompt. Add as many options as you wish in the batch file (I have added some).

Comment: The option `--aux-directory` exists for pdflatex. But it is a MiKTeX specific option.

Comment: Your bat work fine. Now i know where my mistake was. I was testing from my  MikTex installation directory (C:\Programs\MiKTeX29\miktex\bin). For some reason I do not understand if some file (example: 001.tex)  is in that location will give the error that I described. Thank you.

Comment: @karlkoeller Good to know. Where can we find these details for miktex?

Comment: @user45725 From windows vista onwards, writing in Program Files is restricted.

Comment: @HarishKumar `pdflatex --help`

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks :), You are still awake?