# I can't find file `.aux'

Tags: linux, auxiliary-files

I have a Tex file that I am able to compile using TeXnicCenter with no issues on my local computer. I also need to compile it on the server that runs on Linux, and my experience with Linux is limited.

On the terminal, I typed:

```
[user@server myfolder]$ pdflatex -jobname = filename
```

which gives me this error message:

```
! I can't find file `.aux'.
\enddocument ...keatletter \@@input \jobname .aux 
                                                  \fi \@dofilelist \ifdim \f...
```

I found two other similar questions [(1)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544836/i-cant-write-on-file-aux) and [(2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159347/pdflatex-cant-find-aux-file). The question (1) does not really apply to my issue. The question (2) seems a possible solution. It seems that pdflatex is looking for the filename.aux in the wrong folder.

I do not have the filename.aux on my folder differently from question (2). I thought pdflatex would create it when I run it. Nonetheless, I tried:

```
pdflatex --output-directory="/home/user/myfolder" --file-line-error --interaction=nonstopmode "filename.tex"
```

which gives me the same error as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does just `pdflatex filename.tex` work on the server, so without setting the jobname or the output directory?

Comment: It looks a bit like you do `\def\jobname{}` somewhere in the middle of your document, because LaTeX opens the `.aux` file correctly at `\begin{document}`, but can't at `\end{document}`. Try `\edef\x{\jobname}\show\x` before `\end{document}` to see what is the value of `\jobname`.

Comment: @Marijn it works! I was using "-jobname=" because the current script (which I have worked based on) has pdflatex -jobname = "filename" temp > temp2.